# How to exec mplayer with php script

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi

I am programming a web interface for my home automation in php, html, css, js.
The controller is a Raspberry Pi with Debian.
My question was how to exec mplayer with php script?

I've created php script which is running on Raspberry:

```
<?php
exec('mplayer http://www.polskastacja.pl/play/hiphop.pls', $output);
echo implode('<br />', $output);
?>
```

and this is an output: http://justpaste.it/dfe2

mplayer exits and don't stream even when I'll add `</dev/null&` to run in background.

This command: `mplayer http://www.polskastacja.pl/play/hiphop.pls` is valid via ssh and stream is played.

Please help me if You have any clues or ideas how to make it work. When it will be done I have second thing, How to stop it with php as well.

Comment: I'm confused... What is your question?

Comment: I want to run mplayer on linux machine clicking on the button in php web interface ( on the same linux machine ).